# Get <img> src and set as variable via class (id not available)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the URL of a certain image out of the given HTML code

```
<div class="image_div_name">
    <img src="http://www.thisistheimage.com" alt="">
</div>
```

So this is my current code that should solve it:

```
var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name");
var src = picture[0];
```

If I now print picture via console.log, I get the correct div:

```
<div class="image_div_name">
    <img src="http://www.thisistheimage.com" alt="">
</div>
```

However, if I want to access the src, it doesnt seem to work:

```
var src = picture[0].src;
console.log(src);
```

Gives back:

```
undedfined
```

If I try:

```
console.log(picture[0].innerHTML)
```

it gets better and I receive:

```
<img src="http://www.thisistheimage.com" alt="">
```

However I'm looking for way to merely get the URL itself, as in:

```
http://www.thisistheimage.com
```

Can you help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name").firstElementChild.src`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `.image_div_name` doesn't have a `src` attribute, you need to select the child `img` element.

Given the HTML you provided, you could access it using `picture[0].children[0]`:

```
var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name");
var src = picture[0].children[0].src;
```

Rather than using `picture[0].children[0]`, you could also use `picture[0].firstElementChild` to access the first child:

```
var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name");
var src = picture[0].firstElementChild.src;
```

---

Since neither of the above methods gurentee that an `img` element will be selected (since you're selecting the first child element), it would probably be better to use something along these lines instead:

```
var src = document.querySelector('.image_div_name > img').src;
```

..or:

```
var picture = document.querySelectorAll(".image_div_name > img");
var src = picture[0].src;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not targeting the `img`, you are targeting the `<div>`, which is why the `innerHTML` property holds the `<img>` inside. (Images don't have `innerHTML`).

Select the `<img>` instead. I've used [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var picture = document.querySelectorAll(".image_div_name img");
var src = picture[0];
var src = picture[0].src;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (if you are 100% sure your div only has a child `<img>`):

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name");
var src = node[0].children[0].src;
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Andy's answer is helpful I recommend.

```
var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("image_div_name")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
var src = picture.getAttribute('src');
```