# Adding an android smart app banner icon using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the below script to show app smart banner in my website. everything is fine, but the icon didn't appear in chrome (Android).

I tried to add the url of icon and with difference sizes but the issue still exist.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyPage</title>

    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=502838820">
    <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=ru.hh.android">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smart-app-banner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="android-touch-icon" href="android-icon.png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="js/smart-app-banner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new SmartBanner({
          daysHidden: 15,   // days to hide banner after close button is clicked (defaults to 15)
          daysReminder: 90, // days to hide banner after "VIEW" button is clicked (defaults to 90)
          appStoreLanguage: 'us', // language code for the App Store (defaults to user's browser language)
          title: 'MyPage',
          author: 'MyCompany LLC',
          button: 'VIEW',
          store: {
              ios: 'On the App Store',
              android: 'In Google Play',
              windows: 'In Windows store'
          },
          price: {
              ios: 'FREE',
              android: 'FREE',
              windows: 'FREE'
          }
, icon: 'img/icon.png'


          // , theme: '' // put platform type ('ios', 'android', etc.) here to force single theme on all device
          // , icon: '' // full path to icon image if not using website icon image
          // , force: 'ios' // Uncomment for platform emulation
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, just use an `<img>` tag instead of a `<link>` with an `href` set to the image data. You can turn your Javascript into a class and call it in your newly made `<img>` tag and basically have the same result I believe.

Check out these out:
[Changing the image source using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery)

[Get <img> src and set as variable via class (id not available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550718/get-img-src-and-set-as-variable-via-class-id-not-available)